# Is it always possible to change "subset sign ⊂" to "equality sign = "

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove inclusion(subset).

Is it always possible to change "subset sign ⊂" to "equality sign = ".

A quick not that I had to translate the task from another language and some terms can be wrong, let me know. I actually don't really know how and what to prove.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you need to give an example of set A and its subset B such that this sets are not equal or prove that subset of any set is equal to the set. Obviously, the last is not true,so the answer is no, and you need to give a counterexample.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош You're probably right. But do you have any idea how can I prove inclusion(subset)?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the $\subset$ in $\{1\}\subset\{1,2\}$ cannot be changed to $=$, so I guess this is not what you are asking.

I think you are trying to ask about the difference in the uses of $\subseteq, \subset$ and $\subsetneq$. The first denotes a subset, which might potentially be (but not has to be!) the whole larger set itself. The last denotes a subset, in which at least one element of the larger set is not contained. Such a set is also called a *proper subset*. I have seen the symbol in the middle being used for both, so in my opinion it is best to use the outer ones to be clear. In your case you have to figure out how your professor introduced $\subset$, ie. if it means $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$.

Bonus: The symbol $\subsetneq$ should not be confused with $\not\subset$respectively $\not\subseteq$, which means *is not a subset of*.